# Process multiple unique Express JS requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I've got a small Express JS api that I'm building to handle and process multiple incoming requests from the browser and am having some trouble figuring out the best approach to handle them.

The use case is that there's a form, with potentially up-to 30 or so people submitting form data to the Express JS api at any given time, the API then POSTS this data of to some place using axios, and each one needs to return a response back to the browser of the person that submitted the data, my endpoint so far is:

```js
app.post('/api/process', (req, res) => {

  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({ code: 400, success: false, message: "No data was submitted" })
    return
  }

  const application = req.body.Application

  axios.post('https://example.com/api/endpoint', application)
        .then(response => {
          res.status(200).send({ code: 200, success: true, message: response })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          res.status(200).send({ code: 200, success: false, message: error })
        });

})
```

If John and James submit form data from different browsers to my Express JS api, which is forwarded to another api, I need the respective responses to go back to the respective browsers...

Comment: This is isolated and there's not interference, The response will send to correct sender agent automatically, This is ```HTTP``` default behavior in ```express```.

Comment: Cool, my only concern is as part of a larger setup, I'll be changing the POST to be something like: `/api/process/:id` and then have a GET end point that will mean the user can reload their page (an ID stored in the browser locally) will mean once reloaded, they can get the response from an endpoint with their ID

Answer (score 0):

Let's make clear for you, A response of a request will only send to the requester, But if you need to send a process request and send a response like, `hey i received your request and you can use another get route to get the result sometimes later`, then you need to determine which job you mean. So You can generate a UUID when server receives a process request and send it back to the sender as response, `Hey i received your process request, you can check the result of process sometimes later and this UUID is your reference code`. Then you need to pass the `UUID` code as `GET`param or query param and server send you the correct result.
This is the usual way when you are usinf `WebSocket`too. send a process req to server and server sends back a reference UUID code, sometime later server sends the process result to websocket of requester and says `Hey this is the result of that process with that UUID reference code.`

I hope i said clear enough.